# Is it possible to do case insensitive fetch in Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, core-data, nspredicate

I am trying to execute a fetch request on NSManagedObjectContenxt and I want the predicate to be case insensitive.

I tried several solutions that I found but all of them works only on NSArray (filteredArrayUsingPredicate) but not on Core Data.

For example:

My persistent store contains an NSManagedObject, 'Car', with the attribute 'name' and its value is "GMC".

1) The following returns with an empty array:

```
NSFetchRequest* fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
fetch.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Car" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

fetch.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name matches[c] %@", @"gmc"];

NSArray* cars = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil];
```

2) The following crashes with 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS':

```
fetch.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name ==[c] %@", @"gmc"];

NSArray* cars = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil];
```

3) The only fetch that works is:

```
fetch.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", @"GMC"];

NSArray* cars = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil];
```

Is it possible to do case insensitive fetch in Core Data? And how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"UPC ==[c] %@ OR ItemID ==[c] %@", aUPCCode,aUPCCode];
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing in case (2) which leads to a crash when executeFetchRequest is called.

Answer (score 1):

The keywords "like" and "contains" seem to work just fine.

```
fetch.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like[c] %@", @"gmc"];
```

or

```
fetch.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", @"gmc"];
```

More keyword options and details can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-CJBDBHCB

and here
http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/

Comment: The 'like' option returns an empty array.

The 'contains' option crashes: 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS'

Answer (score 0):

Use @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:) with your fetchRequest like:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescr = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Car"];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescr]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name matches[c] %@", @"gmc"]];
```

Then perform your fetch as usual.